# int to string then putting in for

Tags: java, android, android-edittext, int

I'm trying to make an android application where the user enters a value then they press a button below. When they press the button I want it to add the edit text value to itself then display the result on the screen. For example if the user typed in two in the edit text, when they press the button I want the app to do 2+2 then display the result 4 on the screen. Here's what I have so far...

```
int AnsNum;
EditText Km;
Button KmPL;
TextView Ans;

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    Km = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etKm);
    KmPL = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    Ans = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvAns);

    KmPL.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Km = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etKm);
            int etKm = new Integer(Km.getText().toString()).intValue();

            int AnsNum = etKm+etKm;
            Ans.setText(AnsNum);        
        }
    });
}
```

In the main java file and...

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvAns"
    android:textSize="100dp"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="0" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/etKm"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:hint="Km"
    android:textSize="100dp"
    android:inputType="numberSigned" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="75dp"
    android:text="Km per Litres" />
```

in the main.xml file. However whenever I try running the app weather on my phone or on the emulator it says it has stopped unexpectedly please try again. I have tried several times but it just doesnt work.

I understand this is probably a stupid question but I am brand new to programming and it would help me loads if you could teach me what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: Can you post the LogCat error? thanks =]

Comment: *"I understand this is probably a stupid question"*  What question?  I could not find a single '?' in that text.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Km = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etKm);
int etKm = Integer.parseInt(Km.getText().toString());
int AnsNum = etKm+etKm;
Ans.setText(AnsNum+"");
```

I usualy print only number types followed with a + "", because it converts to string...

I can't test it here, so you need to tell me if worked

Comment: "`you cannot create a int TYPE, and assing a Integer OBJECT to it... (it's not good)`" - Why not? The only reason I see, is that Integer object may be null (but this is not the case here), and in that case ClassCastException will be thrown. More over, as you suggested, `int etKm = (int) Km.getText());` here your are doing casting from [CharSequence](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#getText%28%29) object to primitive DataType, it seems this will not compile at all (may be, I am wrong?)

Comment: casting like this: (int) is less time consuming, and if you don't have anything but numbers, will work just as fine... I'm used to use it because i work a lot with C...

Comment: doesn't work :) It says: `Cannot cast from Editable to int`. This is Java, not C. May be you are talking about Km.getText().toString() ?

Comment: You are right, that doesen't work in java... I was programming C, and then i saw this... sorry =]

Comment: This code will be fine with `int etKm = Integer.parseInt(Km.getText().toString());`

Answer (score 0):

I think your main problem is here, when you write:

```
Ans.setText(AnsNum);
```

You are trying to call [TextView.setText(int resId)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html), which is definitely not what you want. Instead, as Ivan Seidel said, you should call

```
Ans.setText("" + AnsNum);
```

converting AnsNum to String using [string concatenation operator](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/String.html) (also, this will be optimized by the compiler to use not the concatenation operator, but StringBuilder class instead, as this is more efficient).

---

Also, instead of this:

```
int etKm = new Integer(Km.getText().toString()).intValue();
```

It would be better to call static method of class Integer [public static Integer valueOf(String s)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#valueOf%28java.lang.String%29) like this:

```
int etKm = Integer.valueOf(Km.getText().toString());
```

it returns Integer **objet**, which is automatically casted to [int](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html) type